# when I set cookie max age in request1,and then make another request2 ,I can not get the max-age I set before

Tags: java, http, cookies

my code is like this:

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("cookie")
    public String testCookie(HttpServletRequest res, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Cookie userCodeCookie = new Cookie("userCode", "sxy");
        userCodeCookie.setPath("/");
        userCodeCookie.setMaxAge(1000000);
        userCodeCookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        userCodeCookie.setDomain(res.getServerName());
        Cookie thirdTokenCookie = new Cookie("SSO_THIRD_TOKEN", "thirdToken");
        thirdTokenCookie.setPath("/");
        thirdTokenCookie.setMaxAge(1000000); 
        response.addCookie(thirdTokenCookie);
        thirdTokenCookie.setDomain(res.getServerName());
        response.addCookie(userCodeCookie);
        return "success";
    }


    @GetMapping("/all-cookies")
    public String readAllCookies(HttpServletRequest request) {

        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            return Arrays.stream(cookies)
                    .map(c -> c.getName() + "=" + c.getValue() + "，expire = " + c.getMaxAge())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        }

        return "No cookies";
    }

}
```

Step 1:
request http://localhost:8080/cookie
then I found cookie is right write in brower,and max-age is right
Setp 2:
request http://localhost:8080/all-cookies
this request response is :

```
SSO_THIRD_TOKEN=thirdToken，expire = -1, userCode=sxy，expire = -1
```

why my max-age is lost?

when i request http://localhost:8080/all-cookies
I want this return
SSO_THIRD_TOKEN=thirdToken，expire = 1000000, userCode=sxy，expire = 1000000